# Function that returns number of significant figures

Tags: excel

I have no idea on how to make a function on excel that returns the number of significant figures in a number. So for example. If I enter 0.0001004 the output would be 4.

Comment: Why would it be 4 in this case?

Comment: Because the significant figures are from 1 to 4 1004 a total of 4 numbers.

Comment: You don't need to laugh, I didn't write a joke here. You can check "Zeros appearing anywhere between two non-zero digits are significant." in [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
=IF(AND(A1<1,A1>0),LEN(MID(A1,IF(ROUND(-LOG10(A1),0)=0,3,ROUND(-LOG10(A1),0)+2),99)),0)
```

First `IF` checks if the input number is in 0-1 range, `ROUND(-LOG10(A1),0)` finds the number of zeros, the `MID` substring from non-zero digit to the end(99), `LEN` check the length.

[image]

Comment: It is returning 3 for 0.43. It should return 2 right?

Comment: Wow! I don't know what you did, but that solves my problem. I need this for numbers under 1 so that works for me. However strictly saying -1 should return 1, 1.2 should return 2 and 10 should also return 2. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @LeonardoSaturninoFerreira added explanation.

Comment: I'm confused why this was the accepted answer. It works as often as it doesn't work. Even in the posted example, it gets 3 of 8 examples wrong. Totally useless.

Comment: @ProfessorFluffy phew, that is harsh, feel free to downvote or add a new answer. The way I understood the question is find numbers between 0 and 1, then count numbers excluding leading zeros. From the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) seems like you are right.

Comment: Didn't mean to sound harsh, but broken formulas cause more harm than good. I am currently motivated to solve this, so the first thing I noticed is that the particular issue I raised is solved if you use ROUNDUP instead of ROUND in both cases. I'll look into it more and come back if I solve it fully.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for any number. It is pretty complex due to the many rules governing sig figs. If you want to use trailing zeros after the decimal, just set your input cell to Text format.

```
=IF(B3="","",IF(ABS(B3)=0,0,LEN((ABS(B3)/10^LEN(ABS(B3)))*10^(LEN(ABS(B3)/10^LEN(ABS(B3)))-LEN(INT(ABS(B3)/10^LEN(ABS(B3))))-1)))+LEN(B3)-LEN(ABS(B3))-IF(LEFT(B3,1)="-",1,0)+IF(OR(LEFT(B3,1)=".",LEFT(B3,2)="-."),1,0))+IF(AND(NOT(ISERROR(FIND(".",B3))),ISERROR(FIND(".",ABS(B3)))),-1,0)
```

This equation is a bit more complicated than absolutely required due to it's ability to handle text input where you get complicating factors like 0.123 vs .123, negative numbers, and trailing zeros (e.g. -.0900).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This small *UDF* will display the number of significant digits displayed in the cell **after** the decimal point:

```
Public Function Sig(r As Range) As Long
    If InStr(r.Text, ".") = 0 Then
        Sig = 0
        Exit Function
    End If

    t = Split(r.Text, ".")(1)
    l = Len(t)
    For i = 1 To l
        If Left(t, 1) = "0" Then
            t = Mid(t, 2)
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    Sig = Len(t)
End Function
```

It is clearly dependent on the *formatting* of the cell

Comment: Gary, sorry for the newbie question, how could I make this function get the number from a cell, let's say A1 and then output the number of sig. figs to cell A2?